# Get Android contacts with type-to-filter functionality, restricted to a specific account

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

I'm trying to:

- Display a list of contacts
- Let the user search through them by typing a query
- Limit search results only to a specific Google/Gmail account.

---

This is how I build the URI for the cursor:

```
// User is searching for 'jo'
String query = "jo";
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(query));

// Restrict the query to contacts from 'example@gmail.com'
Uri.Builder builder = uri.buildUpon();
builder.appendQueryParameter(
    ContactsContract.DIRECTORY_PARAM_KEY, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.Directory.DEFAULT));
builder.appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "example@gmail.com");
builder.appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google");

uri = builder.build();
```

This is the final URI:

```
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/filter/jo?directory=0&account_name=example%40gmail.com&account_type=com.google
```

Currently, this shows search results from *all* accounts on the phone.

---

**NOTE:** If I use [`Contacts.CONTENT_URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_URI) instead of [`Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_FILTER_URI), then specifying the directory/account works as expected, but I can no longer use 'type-to-filter' style search.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Directory.html) does state:

> The most important use case for Directories is search. A Directory
>   provider is expected to support at least `Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI`.

Could anyone help point out what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I added your code in [Google's example for contact retrieving](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html), and with a couple of changes it worked perfectly with my Google for Work account.

The changes I made were:

- remove the line with `DIRECTORY_PARAM_KEY`, as I didn't find it to make any difference
- removed `ContactsQuery.SELECTION` from the return statement, because that constant prevents "invisible" contacts from being displayed.

The changes were made to **ContactsListFragment.java**

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // If this is the loader for finding contacts in the Contacts Provider
    // (the only one supported)
    if (id == ContactsQuery.QUERY_ID) {
        Uri contentUri;

        // There are two types of searches, one which displays all contacts and
        // one which filters contacts by a search query. If mSearchTerm is set
        // then a search query has been entered and the latter should be used.

        if (mSearchTerm == null) {
            // Since there's no search string, use the content URI that searches the entire
            // Contacts table
            contentUri = ContactsQuery.CONTENT_URI;
        } else {
            // Since there's a search string, use the special content Uri that searches the
            // Contacts table. The URI consists of a base Uri and the search string.
            contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsQuery.FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(mSearchTerm));
        }

        // HERE COMES YOUR CODE (except the DIRECTORY_PARAM_KEY line)
        Uri.Builder builder = contentUri.buildUpon();
        builder.appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, "example@mycompany.com");
        builder.appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "com.google");
        contentUri = builder.build();

        // Returns a new CursorLoader for querying the Contacts table. No arguments are used
        // for the selection clause. The search string is either encoded onto the content URI,
        // or no contacts search string is used. The other search criteria are constants. See
        // the ContactsQuery interface.

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                contentUri,
                ContactsQuery.PROJECTION,
                null, // I REMOVED SELECTION HERE
                null,
                ContactsQuery.SORT_ORDER);
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreateLoader - incorrect ID provided (" + id + ")");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this seems to have the same problem.  Initially, it *does* restrict the contacts to the specified account.  But as soon as you start typing a search query, it shows contacts from all accounts.

Comment: Then I should think it's an Android < 5.0 bug, because the very same code works perfectly on my Lollipop Nexus but not on my 4.2 Galaxy tablet.

Comment: I was actually running it on a Moto X (tested on Android 5.0 and with the recent 5.1 update).  Same issue.  Did you get search working correctly too?

Comment: Yes, that´s what I meant, with search and all. Did you remove this line? `builder.appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.DIRECTORY_PARAM_KEY, String.valueOf(ContactsContract.Directory.DEFAULT));`?